# Unable to read date value from pig to hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I have my data processed using pig and stored in an hdfs location(/tmp/output). This data now has to be read into a hive table which point to the same location(/tmp/ouput). But when I try to get the date value from the hive table I shows NULL.
Below are the commands I used:

`STORE DATA into '/tmp/output' USING PigStorage('\u0001');`

When I fire the below query :
`hive -e "select load_date from 'STUDENT'"`

It gives me NULL

`2015-10-06T10:09:00.000-04:00`  is the time format I see in /tmp/output.

Seems like hive is unable to read this format(timestamp in hive). 
How can I convert this format into hive readable one.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have `HCatalog` set up?  If so, you can send the output directly to a Hive table and bypass hdfs.

Comment: Yes I have HCatalog. Can you tell how to move the pig output directly to hive table.

Comment: Create a Hive table with the exact column names and datatypes as the relation in Pig you are wanting to store.  In Pig, change your store command to `STORE DATA INTO hive_db.hive_table USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer()` where `hive_db` and `hive_table` are the names of the hive database/table that you just created.

Comment: Timestamps in text files have to use the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.f...]. If they are in another format declare them as the appropriate type (INT, FLOAT, STRING, etc.) and use a UDF to convert them to timestamps.

Comment: @GoBrewers14 thanks. storing the data directly to hive table worked for me.
`STORE DATA INTO hive_db.hive_table USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer()`

Answer (score 0):

We can use hcatstorer to store the pig output into hive table.but Bydefault hcatstorer consider datatype of input as a string.so at the end ,date column stored in hive table won't have date datatype.it will be string.